# Setting Visible tag of asp:Panel with the inverse of Visible of another asp:Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two panels, one for "View" and the other one for "Edit".

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlView" runat="server" Visible='<%# !pnlEdit.Visible %>'>View</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEdit" runat="server" Visible='<%# !pnlView.Visible %>'>Edit</asp:Panel>
```

You must have gotten the idea what I want to do. Its a non-issue, I know that, but I want to set the tags in a way that when one is hidden the other gets shown itself.

```
pnlView.Visible = true;
```

would automatically hide **pnlEdit**.

Answer (score 0):

Taha,

I would create a method that would check if pnlView is visible, so that the method can set the visibility for pnlEdit to false.

How about that?

Comment: definitely not something I am looking for. I have already mentioned that it is a non issue, it can be done by other methods like setting visible of both elements from code behind. I want it this way that even if I change the visible of one, the other would just take its opposite.

Comment: Sorry misread your post.... And because I'm dutch it could explain the misread hehe english is good but not perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this:

```
pnlView.Visible = !(pnlEdit.Visible)
```

and for 2nd one:

```
pnlEdit.Visible = !(pnlView.Visible)
```

Comment: I think so. What do you want?

Comment: Sorry i thought you want to change it from server side.

Comment: I do, but I would just be changing one from server side and the other should adjust itself on that.